# If condition is throwing the notice

Tags: php

The if condition is throwing the following notice, how to fix this?

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /view_rep.php on line 17
```

Here is my php code

```
if ($check->check_area->id != @$_GET['check_area']) {
  unset($check[$k]);
}
```

I tried the following but still, I can see multiple notices

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

Print_r($check), print thefollowing

```
  [check_area] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5429140
            [url] => /api/v2/checke_areas/5429140
            [name] => Other
        )
```

Comment: Can you share `print_r($check)`?

Comment: @SahilGulati  [check_area] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5429130 [url] => /api/v2/check_areas/5429130

Comment: Please make sure your are on `/view_rep.php` and `line 17` is this `if ($check->check_area->id != @$_GET['check_area']) {
  unset($check[$k]);`

Comment: @SahilGulati Is it exactly same

Comment: can you share your complete code? because your above code is looking fine.

Comment: if `$check` is an array (based on `unset($check[$k]);`) then you should do it like this `$check[k]->check_area->id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `$check` is an array of object(s). If that's the case then change your `if` condition

```
if ($check->check_area->id ...
```

to

```
if ($check['check_area']->id ...
```

Comment: the error now is Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: @user580950 Do `var_dump($check);` and tell us what it's showing. Paste the content in [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: @user580950 From the dump, it can be seen that `$check` is an array, so above solution will work fine. Are you sure you're getting this error *Fatal error: Cannot use object ...* in line 17?

Comment: Yes, If I change the if condition to if ($check['check_area']->id ... I get this 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: @user580950 It's working fine for me. See here, [https://eval.in/788811](https://eval.in/788811). Here are pointers to debug this issue further, 1) Check whether `$check` is an array or not. 2) Make sure you're not using *that* `if` inside any loop. 3) Use `var_dump(...);` to see different variable structures, it'll help you in the long run. I'll delete this answer later if it doesn't resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `$check->check_area->id` to work:

1. `$check` must be an object with a property of `check_area`.
2. `$check->check_area` must be an object with a property of `id`.

One or both of these has not been met if you are getting a `property of a non-object` error.

Try checking whether they are objects before trying to access the property:

```
if ($check instanceof stdClass) {

}
```